# Cannot find input file 'pgfcircflow.tex'

Tags: pdftex, circuitikz

When updating my TexLive bundle, I encountered a problem when using the package `circuitikz`. For some reasons `pdflatex` cannot find the `pgfcircflow.tex` file in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/`. However, when adding the tex file to the directory, it still give the same error:

> ```
> ! I can't find file `pgfcircflow.tex'.
> l.314 \input pgfcircflow.tex
> ```

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}

    \draw (0,0) node[spst](s1){};

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have this file and circuitikz doesn't try to load it. Show a minimal example.

Comment: Is there a way to just neglect this error, so the compiler does not get stuck on it (since you do not have this file). However, when looking to the new Circuitikz package, there is such a kind of file in the repository.

Comment: You shouldn't neglect errors. I just saw that there is a new version of circuitikz on CTAN and I just got if through an update in miktex. But how did you get it in texlive? There are currently no updates until texlive 2017 is released.

Comment: I followed following procedure for installing vanilla texlive: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: I didn't want to know how you got your texlive, but how you got a 3 days old circuitikz in this texlive? Did you install it manually? If yes how?

Comment: This file is really new at the latest release, but it should be within the package. At least it exists in the zipfile at http://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz Perhaps this is an error at miktex? You can get the missing file from the zipfile or from here: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/tree/master/tex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The most recent version was installed during the installation of the vanilla texlive package.

Comment: @sistlind: I've already tried this. For some strange reasons, it still bumps into the same problem.

Comment: Sorry but a vanilla texlive 2016 shouldn't install a 3 days old package, it has been frozen for month. I have no idea how you managed to get (parts) of the new circuitikz, but if you add files to your main texlive tree you need to run mktexlsr so that they are found.